# Renaming a file in Xcode 10 too painful

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, ide

Rename file in the project editor should be higher priority BUG. Apple QA engineers do not think so, I have reported this may times to Apple but it got dropped as process of screening bugs is too slow. How to do this more efficiently?

- Xcode takes 30 seconds to show the new name in the sidebar
- Realize Xcode duplicated the file on disk but didn't remove the one with the old name
- Manually delete old file from Finder
- Check for all the "relative to Group" paths
- Restart Xcode

How to do this without reset? What can SourceKit do to help?

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio Code could be good plan B when it comes to real coding except some work on storyboard. Check out this interesting article: https://nshipster.com/vscode/

Comment: Interesting point and sourceKit is getting much more stable with swift 5. Swift will survive!!!